# Grails 2 hot reloading error for a service containg a static inner class

Tags: grails, groovy

I get the following error whenever I modify a service (while the grails app is running) which contains a static inner class from eclipse. How do I resolve this?

```
ERROR loaded.CurrentLiveVersion  - Unexpected exception whilst trying to call the static initializer on com.x.y.SensorDataProcessorService$SensorProcessedFields
```

The service is SensorDataProcessorService and the static inner class is SensorProcessedFields

Comment: What version of Grails and what version of the JVM?

Comment: Grails 2.0 and Java 1.6(I think!) This happened a couple of years back.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are landing on this page now, this was an old issue that has been resolved. Tickets can be found here:

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9600

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8042

Graeme Rocher comments that it was resolved in 2.1.3

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/2-1-2-loaded-CurrentLiveVersion-Unexpected-exception-whilst-td4638656.html